# How to sort a list of list of characters by sorted index of inner list?

Tags: python, string, list

I want to sort a list of list.

Here is my input list of list:

```
[('H', 'A'), ('H', 'C'), ('H', 'K'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'K'), ('C', 'K')]
```

And I want the output to be like this

```
[('A', 'C'), ('A', 'H'), ('A', 'K'), ('C', 'H'), ('C', 'K'), ('H', 'K')]
```

Comment: Ah, you mean you want to sort the contained tuples too?

Comment: are you sure that this is the syntax of a list of lists?

Comment: the output shows that the inner tuples require sorting too.

Comment: Also, please do share your own attempts at solving a problem, and your research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your output indicates that you need to sort both elements in tuples and the final list. So just do:

```
l = [('H', 'A'), ('H', 'C'), ('H', 'K'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'K'), ('C', 'K')]

print(sorted([tuple(sorted(x)) for x in l]))
```

result:

```
[('A', 'C'), ('A', 'H'), ('A', 'K'), ('C', 'H'), ('C', 'K'), ('H', 'K')]
```

this rebuilds the list with your tuples, now *sorted* inside, and performs a `sort` on those tuples.

Comment: hm, I thought you used a list comprehension and was happy, now I see you use a generator expression and now I'm unhappy... :-)  For some operations a list comprehension will be much faster because the result is cast to a list anyway. And `sorted` besides `str.join` is one of them. If you want to get even faster: `sorted(map(iteration_utilities.chained(sorted, tuple), lst))` (requires an [external library](http://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/cfuncs.html#iteration_utilities.chained), but was just meant as a "nice-to-have-info" :D)

Comment: Oh right: `sorted` needs the full list at once! will fix! I myself comment on all posts using `str.join`. I can't get used to this double parenthesis stuff. Something has to be done some day about it. And this `sorted(map` solution of yours also requires list rebuild since `map` returns an iterator.

Comment: But `iteration_utilities.chained(sorted, tuple)` doesn't need to go through any python layer in between because all 3 functions are implemented in C. That provides more speedup than one loses.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
data=[('H', 'A'), ('H', 'C'), ('H', 'K'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'K'), ('C', 'K')]


print(sorted(list(map(lambda i:(i[0],i[1]) if i[0]<i[1] else (i[1],i[0]),data))))
```

output:

```
[('A', 'C'), ('A', 'H'), ('A', 'K'), ('C', 'H'), ('C', 'K'), ('H', 'K')]
```